# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException - Java - Android - Receiving streaming data and storing in multi-dimensional array Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth, indexoutofboundsexception

I am receiving 30000 strings in real time via bluetooth, about 1000 a second. I am parsing the data as a double and trying to store those 30000 data points into the multi-dimensional `array[30000][1]`.However, when I run the Android application, it crashes after a few points due to an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException`.

I do realize this can be done in a singular array, but I will eventually be increasing the width of the array.

Array Size of Stored = `[30000][1]`

Array Size of convert =`[1]`

BluetoothChat

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
    for (int a = 0; a < 30000; a++) {
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        try {
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Voltage: " + readMessage);
            double[] convert = new double[1];

            for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++) {
                convert[z] = Double.parseDouble(readMessage);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                stored[a][j] = convert[a];
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    finalValue = new HjorthClass(stored);
    if (finalValue.returnSum() == true) {
        seizureResult.setText("A Seizure has been detected");
    }
    break;
```

logcat;

```
04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:311)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    04-04 22:44:17.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14619):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: if your second dimension is [1] you really need it ?

Comment: I will be eventually changing it to [2], [3] in the future. I want to test it works for this first. My hjorthClass also takes a 2D array.

Comment: there are too many arrays and you haven't included the size of all

Comment: I'll edit my question to include the array size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you declare a double array of size 1.

```
double[] convert = new double[1];
```

Then you try to call that array ***convert[a]*** where ***a*** could be from 0 to 2999, as soon as ***a > 0*** it is out of bounds.

```
stored[a][j]= convert[a]; // a > 0 ? if yes then out of bounds
```

There is your error. My guess is it should be:

```
stored[a][j]= convert[j];
```

Comment: Well you did fix the ArrayIndexOutofBoundException, however, I get this error on my Android -"Activity Bluetooth Chat(in application BluetoothChat) is not responding. I have two options, for close or wait.

Comment: Probably because you loop in the gui thread. You should start a separate thread and run it in the background, then collect the results somehow.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I do not understand.

Comment: The graphical user interface (gui) runs in a thread that draws and paints your screen. If you run a loop in between, and that loop takes some time to finish then it blocks the gui thread, finishes the execution of your loop and then updates the gui again, potentially after seconds or more. So you run in sequence. By running your code in a separate thread you run in parallel and the gui thread keeps updating normally.

Comment: Here is an example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/thread/android-thread-example/

Comment: Is there any way to avoid threads or any way to manipulate the code I have here instead?

Comment: if you want to run operations that take more then milliseconds to finish there is no real alternative but threads.

Comment: But it is really not that difficult to implement, i would just try it out if i was you. Keep your code in a separate class and use a Runnable to call it.